# How can I set an image in a GridView for a limited time?

Tags: android, gridview

I'm creating a very simple sound box application. What I want to do is to change an ImageView just during the time of a sound and then put back the first image. The thing is I have no idea of how to do that.
Here is my code :

### SoundAdapateur.java :

```
public class SoundAdaptateur extends ArrayAdapter<Sound>{

    private Sound[] items;
    private Context context = null;
    private MediaPlayer mp = null;

    public SoundAdaptateur(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Sound[] items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        SoundHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            final ImageView iv = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            holder = new SoundHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.txtDescription = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.description);

            row.setTag(holder);

            iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mp != null)
                        mp.reset();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, items[position].getSoundResourceId());
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        }else {
            holder = (SoundHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Sound sound = items[position];

        if(sound != null){
            holder.txtDescription.setText(sound.getDescription());
            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.muscle1);
        }

        return row;
    }

    static class SoundHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtDescription;
    }
}
```

### MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Sound[] mSounds = null;
    private SoundAdaptateur mAdapter = null;
    private GridView mListView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.list1);

        mSounds = new Sound[]{
                new Sound("test 1", R.raw.test1,R.drawable.muscle1),
                new Sound("test 2", R.raw.test2,R.drawable.muscle1),
                new Sound("test 3", R.raw.test3,R.drawable.muscle1),
                new Sound("test 4", R.raw.test4,R.drawable.muscle1),
                new Sound("test 5", R.raw.test5,R.drawable.muscle1),
                new Sound("test 6", R.raw.test6,R.drawable.muscle1),
                new Sound("test 7", R.raw.test7,R.drawable.muscle1),
                new Sound("test 8", R.raw.test8,R.drawable.muscle1),
        };

        mAdapter = new SoundAdaptateur(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, mSounds);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}
```

I tried to change the image at the beginning of the sound and then do a while loop until the end of the sound and put back the first image but it didn't work and it wasn't a clean code. 

Here is what I tried :

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.muscle1);
                    if(mp != null)
                        mp.reset();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, items[position].getSoundResourceId());
                    mp.start();
                    try {
                    while (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        wait();
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
               iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.muscle);
                }
            });
```

Do you have any idea of how I can do ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your image doing this:

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.muscle1);
....
mp.start();

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

              //change image here
              iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.muscle);

        }
    });
```